# Undisplayed question in form updating a case property

Tags: commcare

If I have a form that has a question that is not always displayed but does update a case property, when the question is NOT displayed, does it overwrite whatever the property is with '' or an empty value? Or does the question only update the property if it is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is not displayed, then that datum will never be sent to the server. Thus, the case property will not be updated. The property will only be written to when the question is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is correct; a question will only update a case property (or the value of a calculate condition for another question) if its display condition evaluates to true.